# Remove Ctrl + Alt Shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

When I was reinstalling Ubuntu 21.10 a few months ago I was prompted to set a shortcut to switch my keyboard input languages, and I set this to `Ctrl + Alt`. This combination however, interferes with another program I'm using, so I would like to remove the input language switched shortcut. However, I cannot find where the `Ctrl + Alt` shortcut is set. When I look under Keyboard Shortcuts, `Switch to next input source` is set to `Super + Space` not `Ctrl + Alt`.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 is going EOL in a week, might be a good time to upgrade, since upgrading after EOL is much more difficult

Comment: I've seen this for really old Ubuntu, no idea if it still works: under **system settings** -> **keyboard layout** -> **options** click "keys to change layout". Might have slightly different names at this point, might not exist at all, but try looking there.